# Dart2JS compiler exception when minify is used on google_maps package

Tags: google-maps, dart, dart2js, angular-dart

I have been building a web application with Dart and AngularDart upon Google Maps. I noticed a problem since the begin of the process even though I tested the development Dart sdk, and today the latest dart sdk (version 1.0.0.10_R30798) and still face the problem.

Firstly the packages I am using are shadow_dom, google_maps and AngularDart.

When I build my application WITH --no-minify option it works great, even in all the browsers after fiddling around with shadow_dom for a week (I should add the shadow_dom script BEFORE everything else to work properly).

The problem is that when I build normally (minify) or even directly using Dart2JS compiler with the --minify option the application does not run and I get an exception.

[image: Non-minified version]
[image: Minified version]

Above you can see the two cases, where in the first the application loads the google maps correctly and in the second picture the google maps are not loaded and I get that exception.

More importantly is that if I use a 3rd party minifier to minify the original main.dart.js file (the unminified) it works perfectly fine.

Thank you

Comment: What is the version of your `google_maps` package ?

Comment: In the packages inside my folder it says 2.0.3.
I did pub install and then pub upgrade already.

Comment: Long shot, but there are some resources that get an 404 error. Are they related? Are they some .js files needed for the dart application?

Comment: No the main.dart not found is because I am using the JS code instead of the dart code in production.

Comment: We will release a new version of SDK soon (hopefully within the next few days). If you still see this issue at that point, please file a bug on dartbug.com (ideally with the original source code). Thanks.

Comment: OK, I will try the new version as soon as it get out. As for the source code it might be difficult since it is an internal project, but I will provide a source code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The *2.x* version of [google_maps package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps) has removed the dependency on [dart:mirrors](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_mirrors.html) and is only based on [dart:js](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_js.html). So the minification problem should come from another part of your code.

Moreover I just tested [the map-simple example](https://github.com/a14n/dart-google-maps/tree/master/example/01-basics/map-simple) with `--minify` and it works.

Comment: Hmm, the thing is that only an Http GET request is done before the map loads, and as you can see the map does not even show up. I will debug it more thoroughly then, if the problem is somewhere else in AngularDart

Answer (score 0):

Usually this can be solved with the `@MirrorsUsed` annotation if it's 3rd-party code that is affected.
It's easier with your own code where you just have to add `@reflectable` to the affected functions/methods/fields to ensure they are retained.

It may be hard to find what functions/methods/fields should be included when the names are minified.
Maybe you can gain some knowledge by looking at the stack trace.

Minification usually drops code that is not referenced anywhere.
In Polymer this is because polymer expressions `{{ expr }}` in HTML are not yet considered.
If you invoke parts of the code only by reflection this is also not recognized.

I have no experience with regard to Angular and minification.
 This is just generic advice about problems with minification through `pub build`.

Comment: Yes but the problem is that I have already added the google_maps package I use in the @MirrorsUsed targets. Basically I added all the packages I use in order to be sure that it is not about them.

Comment: I saw that for Angular packages are added to @MirrorsUsed. I'm not sure how that exactly works. I guess this notifies dart2JS that all not referenced code can be dropped to achieve better results with minification because this is usually mentioned when the resulting code size is to large. To retain code that gets dropped by default you have to mention functions/methods/fields explicitly so they are retained. 

As mentioned I don't know enough about the effect of adding packages.

Comment: Yes, I know that and I have added many angular packages but it seems that more are needed. I will start by adding everything and then removing one by one and see how it goes. Thanks.

At the moment I have these:         'angular',
        'angular.core',
        'angular.core.dom',
        'angular.core.parser',
        'angular.routing',
        NodeTreeSanitizer,
        'angular.filter',
        'angular.perf',
        'perf_api',
        'angular.directive',
)
as targets if anyone finds the problem.